# Resharper Intellisense missing Exception Description

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Can't seem to find any answers in here / on google, I know I should probably ask at ReSharper support but I thought I might get a quicker answer here.

I have created XML documentation for an Exception as per the following code;

```
/// <summary>
/// Commits any changes to the Database and raises the Saved event.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Exception description goes here.</exception>
void Commit();
```

But when viewing the method, I only get the following;

[image: Missing]

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get the "Exception description goes here." to appear in the Intellisense popup?

I'm using R# Version 7.1.3 and Visual Studio Professional 2012 Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3 if that helps. I've tried to rebuild and clean the project, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is similar feature request in tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-333690.
Please, vote.